# Was given this code on SO, but how to make it output to stdout instead?

Tags: c, shell, solaris

a kind user here gave me some code to work with for a command line shell, but I want it to output to `stdout` and `stderr` instead of using a screen or whatever it is doing right now. I am new to C so I don't know anything about converting it. I also need its ability to detect arrow keys preserved... I'm trying to make a simplistic bash clone. This is what I have right now, it's about 50% my code and 50% others'... yes, it is buggy. There are large sections commented out because they were no longer being used or because they were broken. Ignore them. :)

The particular difficulty is in the use of `draw_frame()` in `main()`.

```
#include "os1shell.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* standard unix functions, like getpid()       */
#include <sys/types.h>  /* various type definitions, like pid_t         */
#include <signal.h> /* signal name macros, and the kill() prototype */
#include <ncurses/curses.h> /* a library for cursor-based programs  */

#include <poll.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <time.h>

/** VT100 command to clear the screen. Use puts(VT100_CLEAR_SCREEN) to clear
 *  the screen. */
#define VT100_CLEAR_SCREEN "\033[2J"

/** VT100 command to reset the cursor to the top left hand corner of the
 *  screen. */
#define VT100_CURSOR_TO_ORIGIN "\033[H"

struct frame_s {
int x;
int y;
char *data;
};

char* inputBuffer;  /* the command input buffer, will be length 65 and null
                * terminated. */
char** cmdHistory;  /* the command history, will be no longer than 20
                * elements and null terminated. */
int historySize = 0;

void addToHistory(char* newItem) {
    char** h;
    int historySize = 0;
    for (historySize; historySize < 21; ++historySize) {
        if (cmdHistory[historySize] == NULL) break;
    }
    if (historySize == 20) {
        char** newPtr = cmdHistory + sizeof(char *);
        free(cmdHistory[0]);
        cmdHistory = newPtr;
        h = (char**)realloc(cmdHistory,21*sizeof(char *));
        cmdHistory = h;
        cmdHistory[19] = newItem;
        cmdHistory[20] = NULL;
    } else {
        h = (char**)realloc(cmdHistory,(historySize+2)*sizeof(char *));
        cmdHistory = h;
        cmdHistory[historySize] = newItem;
        cmdHistory[historySize+1] = NULL;
    }
}

/* Some help from http://stackoverflow.com/users/1491/judge-maygarden*/
char** getArguments(char* input) {
    char** arguments;
    int k = 0;
    char* tokenized;
    arguments = calloc(1, sizeof (char *));
    tokenized = strtok(input, " &");
    while (tokenized != NULL) {
        arguments[k] = tokenized;
        ++k;
        arguments = realloc(arguments, sizeof (char *) * (k + 1));            
        tokenized = strtok(NULL, " &");
    }

    // an extra NULL is required to terminate the array for execvp()
    arguments[k] = NULL;

    return arguments;
}

void printHistory(struct frame_s *frame) {
    snprintf(frame->data, frame->x, "\n\n");
    char** currCmd = cmdHistory;
    while (*currCmd != NULL) {
        snprintf(frame->data[(2*frame->x)], frame->x, "%s\n", *currCmd);
        currCmd++;
    }
    snprintf(frame->data, frame->x, "\n\n");
}

/* Some help from http://stackoverflow.com/users/659981/ben*/
static int draw_frame(struct frame_s *frame) {
    int row;
    char *data;
    int attrib;

    puts(VT100_CLEAR_SCREEN);
    puts(VT100_CURSOR_TO_ORIGIN);

    for (   row = 0, data = frame->data;
        row  < frame->y;
        row++, data += frame->x ) {
        //  0 for normal, 1 for bold, 7 for reverse.
        attrib = 0;

        //  The VT100 commands to move the cursor, set the attribute,
        //  and the actual frame line.
        fprintf(    stdout,
                "\033[%d;%dH\033[0m\033[%dm%.*s",
                row + 1,
                0,
                attrib, frame->x, data);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return (0);
}

/* Some help from http://stackoverflow.com/users/659981/ben*/
int main(void) {
    const struct timespec timeout = { .tv_sec = 1, .tv_nsec = 0 };
    struct frame_s frame;
    struct termios tty_old;
    struct termios tty_new;
    unsigned char line[65];     // the input buffer
    unsigned int count = 0;     // the count of characters in the buff
    int ret;
    struct pollfd fds[1];
    sigset_t sigmask;
    struct tm *tp;
    time_t current_time;

    cmdHistory = (char**)calloc(21,sizeof(char *)); // initialize the
                            // command history
    cmdHistory[20] = NULL;      // null terminate the history
    int histInd = 0;        // an index for the history for arrows

    int t;
    int r;
    char** downTemp;
    char** enterTemp;

    //  Set up a little frame.
    frame.x = 80;
    frame.y = 32;
    frame.data = malloc(frame.x * frame.y);

    if (frame.data == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No memory\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    memset(frame.data, ' ', frame.x * frame.y);

    //  Get the terminal state.
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &tty_old);
    tty_new = tty_old;

    //  Turn off "cooked" mode (line buffering) and set minimum characters
    //  to zero (i.e. non-blocking).
    tty_new.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tty_new.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;

        // Set the terminal attributes.
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tty_new);

    //  Un-mask all signals while in ppoll() so any signal will cause
    //  ppoll() to return prematurely.
    sigemptyset(&sigmask);

    fds[0].events = POLLIN;
    fds[0].fd = STDIN_FILENO;

    // Loop forever waiting for key presses. Update the output on every key
    // press and every 1.0s (when ppoll() times out).
    do {
        fd_set rdset;
        int nfds = STDIN_FILENO + 1;

        FD_ZERO(&rdset);
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &rdset);
        ret = pselect(nfds, &rdset, NULL, NULL, &timeout, &sigmask);

        if (ret < 0) {          // check for pselect() error.
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                continue;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &rdset)) {
            ret = read(STDIN_FILENO,&line[count],sizeof(line)-count);

//  do {
//      fds[0].revents = 0;
//      ret = poll(fds, sizeof(fds) / sizeof(struct pollfd), 1000);
//
//      if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN) {
//          ret = read(STDIN_FILENO,&line[count],sizeof(line)-count);

            if (ret > 0) {
                line[count + ret] = '\0';

                if (strcmp(&line[count], "\033[A") == 0) {
                    if (histInd > 0) {
                        --histInd;
                    }
                    count = 0;
                    if(cmdHistory[histInd]!=NULL) {
                        snprintf(&frame.data[(2*frame.x)],
                            frame.x,
                            "hist: %s",
                            cmdHistory[histInd]);
                        strcpy(line, cmdHistory[histInd]);
                    }
                } else if (strcmp(&line[count],"\033[B")==0) {
                    char** downTemp = cmdHistory;
                    r = 0;
                    while (*downTemp != NULL) {
                        ++downTemp;
                        ++r;
                    }
                    if (histInd < r-1 && r!= 0) {
                        ++histInd;
                    }
                    count = 0;
                    if(cmdHistory[histInd]!=NULL) {
                        snprintf(&frame.data[(2*frame.x)],
                            frame.x,
                            "hist: %s",
                            cmdHistory[histInd]);
                        strcpy(line, cmdHistory[histInd]);
                    }
                } else if (line[count] == 127) {
                    if (count != 0) {
                        line[count] = '\0';
                        count -= ret;
                    }
                    snprintf(&frame.data[(2*frame.x)], frame.x, "backspace");
                } else if (line[count] == '\n') {
                    char** arguments = getArguments(line);
                    snprintf(   &frame.data[(2*frame.x)],
                            frame.x, 
                            "entered: %s",
                            line);
                    if (count > 0) {
                        int hasAmpersand = 0;
                        char* cmd = (char*)
                            malloc(65*sizeof(char));
                        strcpy(cmd, line);
                        addToHistory(cmd);
                        /*
                        char* temp = cmd;
                        while (*temp != '\0') {
                            if (*temp == '&') {
                                hasAmpersand = 1;
                            }
                            ++temp;
                        }
                        pid_t pid;
                        pid = fork();
                        if (pid == 0) {
                            int exeret;
                            exeret = execvp(*arguments, 
                                    arguments);
                            if (exeret < 0) {
                                snprintf(
                                    &frame.data[
                                        (2*frame.x)],
                                    frame.x,
                                    "Exec failed.\n\n");
                                exit(1);
                            }
                        } else if (pid < 0) {
                            snprintf(
                                &frame.data[
                                    (2*frame.x)],
                                frame.x,
                                "Fork failed.\n\n");
                            exit(1);
                        } else if (pid > 0) {
                            if (!hasAmpersand) {
                                wait(NULL);
                            }
                            free(arguments);
                            snprintf(frame.data,
                                frame.x,
                                "\n\n");
                        }*/
                    } else {
                        free(arguments);
                    }
                    enterTemp = cmdHistory;
                    t = 0;
                    while (*enterTemp != NULL) {
                        ++enterTemp;
                        ++t;
                    }
                    if (t > histInd) histInd = t;
                    count = 0;
                } else {
                    //snprintf( frame.data,
                    //      frame.x, 
                    //      "char: %c",
                    //      line[count]);
                    count += ret;
                }
            }
        }

        // Print the current time to the output buffer.
        //current_time = time(NULL);
        //tp = localtime(&current_time);
        //strftime( &frame.data[1 * frame.x],
        //      frame.x,
        //      "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",
        //      tp);

        //  Print the command line.
        line[count] = '\0';
        snprintf(   frame.data,
                frame.x, 
                "OS1Shell -> %s",
                line);

        draw_frame(&frame);
    } while (1);

    //  Restore terminal and free resources.
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tty_old);
    free(frame.data);
    int n = 0;
    while (n < 21) {
        free(cmdHistory[n]);
        ++n;
    }
    free(cmdHistory);

    return (0);
}
```

Any help getting it to act more like bash would be highly appreciated! Part of the credit is for using `stderr` correctly anyways, so it would definitely help to take the `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr` approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me it ***already is*** going to STDOUT

```
fprintf(    stdout,
        "\033[%d;%dH\033[0m\033[%dm%.*s",
        row + 1,
        0,
        attrib, frame->x, data);
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: Oh, okay... then what if I type in a command that is supposed to output more than 32 lines of text? Isn't the frame bounded to 32 lines?

Comment: No, there are no limits of 32 lines. The '\033' value is octal for decimal value 27, and this is the ESC character used for ANSI escape codes, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code.

Comment: @user: This type of *here is my 200 line code block, fix this for me* question usually requires some form of bounty.  My advice is to get a book on `C` because if there is one thing people like to see on SO (and other technical forums in general) is that you did your due diligence to understand the problem before posting the question.

Comment: @SiegeX - He did say he did 50% of it. He had no reason to admit that somebody else did the other 50%, yet he did. I think we should also appreciate his honesty. Your comment and advice is perfectly valid for a generic "fix my code" question.

Comment: @hlovdal See `frame.y = 32;` in the code. The fact is that this code is absolutely hopeless.